# How to change bass guitar tuning in Sibelius 8?

Tags: bass-guitar, sibelius, scordatura

How can I change my bass guitar tuning? In this case I want to have a whole step down standard tuning (DGCFAD) (for 4 string bass it should be DGCF). How can I do it?

Comment: You appear to be tuning the six string bass in the same way as an ordinary guitar. And often, a six string will go from low B to high C. Interested as to why. Usually, basses are tuned with all their strings a fourth apart. I realise it's a virtual bass!

Comment: @Tim  I'm using a 4 string bass, so it's tuning will be the same as 4 bottom strings of the regular guitar - got it thanks. But how the hack can I change a tuning in Sibelius. It's very easy to do it Guitar Pro, but not in Sibelius as I guess.

Comment: @EugenEray if you are using the standard 4 string bass, why did you post the guitar tuning tuned one step down?

Comment: @Shevliaskovic  To indicate a standard tuning a whole step down.

Comment: @EugenEray no need to add the guitar tuning

Comment: @Shevliaskovic  Ok, but do you know the answer?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Sibelius 8 but in 7 you have to create a new instrument using the Edit Instrument menu. Select 4-string Bass Guitar [tab], select New Instrument, then edit staff type. There you can change the pitches of each individual string. You can do the same to make a transposing notation staff if you want to read in E standard tuning.